# How do i take the table from this website into a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, data-analysis

I have this link from forbes.. http://www.forbes.com/global2000/list/ . I need to take the top 2000 companies table into a dataframe for analysis. How do i do that?

Comment: Do HTML Scraping..  http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/

Answer (score 3):

You can directly use `pd.read_json`, as the underlying table is generated from a `json` resposne.

Hint: Check the network tab of browser, for the `xhr` request, for the `url`.

```
In [38]: df = pd.read_json('http://www.forbes.com/ajax/list/data?year=2016&uri=glo
    ...: bal2000&type=organization')

In [40]: df.shape
Out[40]: (2001, 16)

In [41]: df.head(2)
Out[41]:
    assets            ceo         country    headquarters  imageUri  \
0  32718.0    Inge Thulin   United States       Minnesota        3m
1   7454.0  Simon Borrows  United Kingdom  United Kingdom  3i-group

              industry  marketValue      name  position  profits  rank  \
0        Conglomerates     102175.0        3M       200   4833.0   200
1  Investment Services       6685.0  3i Group      1562    925.0  1562

   revenue squareImage      state thumbnail       uri
0  30274.0         NaN  Minnesota       NaN        3m
1    485.0         NaN        NaN       NaN  3i-group
```